# Excel Sumif formula is not working

Tags: excel-formula

I have a data like below in the excel from A1 to F3

```
Task    Mon Tue Wed Thu Friday
Row 1: A    2   2   2   2   2    
Row 2: B    2   2   2   2   2
```

I wanted to add all the values which is under row which matches "A". I am using below formula but it is not showing correct count.

```
=SUMIF(A1:F3,"A",B2:F3)
```

which is giving wrong sum.

Can you please help me in this.

Comment: Which row are Mon, Tue.... in?

Comment: Row 1: has Task, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri
Row 2: A 2 2 2 2 2
Row 3: B 2 2 2 2 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$3="A")*$B$2:$F$3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, does it have any performance issue?

Comment: Yes, it is an array type formula so keep the references to only the dataset.